# Can't we write an executable statement for #define?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Why do I get 27? Can't `#define` take executable statement 5+2?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define x 5+2
void main()
{
    int i;
    i=x*x*x;
    printf("%d",i):
    getch();
}
```

Output:

> 27

I should get 343 as answer.

Comment: There are tons of duplicates to this ... - fair enough, those are difficult to find.

Comment: @alk It is interesting that this OP assumed that if it compiled but did not produce the expected result, that must mean it was somehow forbidden to use macros a certain way (“can't”) whereas the OP in the linked question assigned blame to the compilation platform (“strange”).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Indeed, a sociologically/psychologically analysis on various aspects round here might also be an interesting project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is *not* an executable statement, it is an *expression*. An no, it shouldn't be 343, because the expression is not parenthesized. Because of that, multiplication takes precedence over addition, so the expression being evaluated is

```
5+2*5+2*5+2
```

which is

```
5+(2*5)+(2*5)+2 = 27
```

This little example illustrates the dangers of macros. You should always parenthesize the content of macros representing expressions. In addition, you should always parenthesize parameters of macro expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are tricky, because they are not functions, just text substitutions. Therefore, your expression becomes:

```
i=5+2*5+2*5+2;
```

Solution: use constant, or wrap your macro in parentheses

```
#define x (5+2)
```